# Find a line with leading and/or trailing space(s)

Tags: regex

Create a regular expression that will find a line with leading and/or trailing space(s).

Guys, I have no idea how to start. Anyone care to lighten me up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To see if such lines exist, you can use this simple regex (see [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/mM4sG1)):

```
^ | $
```

To actually match the lines, use this (see [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/iP6vN2)):

```
^(?: .*$|.* $)
```

To match a the spaces, use this (see [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/hE7kI3)):

```
^ +| +$
```

Comment: Hi thanks.To be honest I'm quite confused of what does "matching" means..Does it mean that when I type the regex at regex tester site (regex101 for example),it will only highlight the spaces?For example I type " abc ",it would only highlight the spaces and not the string "abc"..Someone clear me up?

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh What language are you using? On my regex101 demo, you can see that the MATCH is the highlighted string, i.e., the lines you said you wanted.

Comment: If i type "Hello_ _ _ _ _" (ignoring " " and each _ _ are spaces),it would highlight Hello and the spaces..is that what is it supposed to be?

I thought it should highlight only the spaces..Sorry I'm a near regex learner

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh Yes, that's what you asked for: `find the lines which has leading and trailing spaces`. That's not what you want?

Comment: OH YES....I GET IT..THE LINES..HAHA...Supposed the question is to only highlight the spaces,it would be harder right?I still couldn't figure it out

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh No, that's easy. That's my first regex, at the top. I'll make a demo too.

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh Okay, added two more demos AND one more case, so you can see how to match a single space (just to find the lines) or to match **all** the spaces. Let me know if this is what you're looking for.

Comment: I tried doing that too.Problem is if the string is " _ _ Hello _ _",it only highlights the starting spaces and not the ending ones

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh Yes it does. See demo #3.

Comment: No problem man.You helped me a lot.Just one last question.What does /g (global) means?

Btw I did clicked on the checkmark right? Sorry man it's my first time using this site.

Comment: @Zhi You might want to use `\s` instead of a literal space if you want to match non-space white-space characters as well (e.g. tabs).

Comment: The `g` in regex101 just means to find all the matches. Without it, it only finds the first match. This is a syntax used by some languages like Python and Java.

Comment: @jbaums FYI we has the `\s` convo in an earlier iteration of the question, the trade-off is that `\s` also eats up newlines. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your regex would be like this to find the lines which has leading and trailing spaces,

```
^ +.* +$
```

Comment: Hi thanks.To be honest I'm quite confused of what does "matching" means..Does it mean that when I type the regex at regex tester site (regex101 for example),it will only highlight the spaces?For example I type " abc ",it would only highlight the spaces and not the string "abc"..Someone clear me up??

Comment: You should consider taking a look at some introductory resources, e.g. [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
/^ .*|.+ $/m
```

Comment: Hi thanks.To be honest I'm quite confused of what does "matching" means..Does it mean that when I type the regex at regex tester site (regex101 for example),it will only highlight the spaces?For example I type "  abc  ",it would only highlight the spaces and not the string "abc"..Someone clear me up?

Comment: @ZhiJTeoh: No, it will highlight all the line where there are trailing or leading spaces.